# Api access over virtual host and port?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, webserver, laravel-passport

I installed laravel passport and access my api over `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api`, that works.

But I have my valet virutalhost like `https://myapp.test`, I would wish to access now the api over `https://myapp.test:8000/api`, is that possible? 
Will I have also api directly online on my domain?

I want to avoid to run everytime `php artisan serve`

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is to add middleware called Cors:
`php artisan make:middleware Cors`

and add following code to `app/Http/Middleware/Cors.php`

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    return $next($request)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
}
```

Next step is to add following line to `app/Http/Kernel.php`.

```
In $routeMiddleware array
'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
```